# Use JQ and similar to filter IPv4 and IPv6 addresses in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, filter, jq

I'm trying to extract IPv4 and IPv6 addresses from a Cloudflare firewall rule, to use in another command.

Here's a full example `json` response that I want to filter:

```json
{
    "result": {
        "id": "78839c481cd8424fa8f0f06abd33b55f",
        "paused": false,
        "description": "Test",
        "action": "block",
        "priority": 1,
        "filter": {
            "id": "68f2efc4fa6e43f584dd4b60aca09901",
            "expression": "(ip.src in {192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 2408:14c:dc83:9119:f9f6:c105:923:a5e3})",
            "paused": false
        },
        "created_on": "2020-11-02T13:48:31Z",
        "modified_on": "2020-11-02T13:49:02Z"
    },
    "success": true,
    "errors": [],
    "messages": []
}
```

I just want to extract any IPv4 or IPv6 address that is inside the expression field, so in this case, `192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2`

How can I do this in `bash`?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have access to the `jq` utility, or can you get it installed. It will be trivial to solve with this tool. And a good question on StackOverlow will include your best attempt at solving the problem. We're here to help you fix your understanding of programming, but not to write the code for you. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With your JSON, an invocation along the lines of:

```
jq -r '.result.filter.expression
  | capture("{(?<ips>[^}]*)}").ips' example.json
```

would yield the string of IP addresses:

```
192.168.1.1 192.168.1.2 2408:14c:dc83:9119:f9f6:c105:923:a5e3
```

The rest should be easy sailing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

My actual `json` is returned in the variable `$RULE`.
How can I use `$RULE` with the JQ command you posted?

Comment: One option - instead of `example.json`, write: `<<< "$RULE"`